# Errors in running a downloaded source code from code.google.com

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded the source of an android application, MyTracks , from `code.google.com`. 
When I import the application into eclipse, it shows a lot of errors in the application, which include errors like, the import being invalid, methods used which have not been defined etc.
As an example `com.google.android.apps.mytracks.content.TracksColumns;` has been imported in one of the java files, but this gives an error that this import can't be resolved.

Comment: you need to add the dependencies like image files, external libraries etc.

Comment: i imported the dependencies like the libraries and have cleaned the project. Though the number of error has reduced,earlier there were about 2,000 now they are 56,.